# How can we add a XML file content to another XML file (at specific position)

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to add a XML file content to another XML file by using Xslt

How can we do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `document()` function to load other XML documents.  If you want to simply insert the content of the second document verbatim in your output tree you can use

```
<xsl:copy-of select="document('otherfile.xml')/*" />
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to Ian Roberts' answer, if you want to insert the second document as the last child of the outermost element, do this":

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*, node()"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="document('otherfile.xml')"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```